# Conditional formatting- use a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

[image]I'm getting a bit tripped up with Excel. I've got 5 columns of retirement account contributions and balances over 30 years, and I'm trying to highlight the year where the year-end balance first crosses $1,000,000 by using conditional formatting > new rule > use a formula. I keep striking out so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula works for me, using Excel 2010:

```
=AND($A2>=1000000;$A1<1000000)
```

[image]

Quite simply, it checks if the cell is larger 1,000,000 and if the neighbouring cell is less than 1,000,000.

If row 1 can be a value in your dataset you'll need to put in some special handling for that, the same goes if the first row of data can be the row to be highlighted and the header of the column doesn't translate to a value less than 1,000,000 (as you can see from the screenshot). The simplest solution may be to just insert separate handling for the first value in these cases. Apart from this, I think it should be fairly trivial to adapt the formula to your needs.